# How to fix issues with Room Finder not loading rooms

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

We have multiple users experience issues with room finder. Room finder will not load the available rooms.

I didn't setup the rooms so I think there may be something wrong with how the rooms are setup.

Is there a missing setting or anything else I could check or test?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, i'm here to confirm the progress of your thread, is there any update? If your problem has been fixed, you could mark the best answer or share your solutions. Have a nice day:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Yes a Distribution group of a type Room List is required for the Outlook Room finder to display the rooms available. The user will still need to select the Room List in the Outlook Room Finder as it won't show in the Outlook Room Finder automatically.

1. Verify a room list doesn't already exist that fits the description of the request
2. add the distribution group of a room list type if it doesn't exist
3. add the room resource mailboxes as members of the distribution group room list

Answer (score 2):

What's the build version of your office 365?
Do you have a roomlist distribution group which was added the room mailbox in it? Please try to **[connect to Exchange Online powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/basic-auth-connect-to-exo-powershell?view=exchange-ps#connect-to-exchange-online-powershell)** and run the following cmdlets to view that:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -RecipientTypeDetails RoomList
$roomgroups = Get-DistributionGroup -RecipientTypeDetails RoomList
foreach($roomgroup in $roomgroups){Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $roomgroup.Name}
```

[image]

Based on my test, the issue could happen with earlier versions of office 365, please try to update your office 365 to the latest version and see if there is any difference.

Besides, here is a similar thread about **`Room Finder`**, please check if it's helpful to you: **[Room List and Room Finder not working](https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/f6zco5/room_list_and_room_finder_not_working/)**

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was modified GAL that didn't display roomlists (why would you want to display that in user's addressbook?)
No roomlists in GAL = no roomlists in room finder.